# hide div if two conditions are true

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

If either one of `$image` and `$content` are not empty  `.section-intro` should be output to the page. i.e if both are empty `.section-intro` should not output. For some reason my code isn't outputting anything to page despite at least one of the fields not being empty. Any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<?php if(have_rows('image_slideshow')): 
    $image = get_sub_field('image');
    $content = get_sub_field('centered_text');
?>
<?php if(!empty($image) || !empty($content)): ?>
    <div class="section-intro">
        <div class="slides">
            <?php while( have_rows('image_slideshow') ): the_row(); ?>
            <div class="slide intro"> 
                <?php if(!empty($image)): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
                <?php endif; ?>
            
                <?php echo $content; ?>
            </div>           
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: maybe I missunderstand you, but as I read it your description contradicts itself. _"For some reason my code isn't outputting anything to page despite at least one of the fields not being empty"_ - that is exactly what you describe in your first sentence, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `AND` instand of `OR`

```
<?php if(!empty($image) && !empty($content)): ?>
```

Also, your full code must be like this

```
    <?php 
       if(have_rows('image_slideshow')): 
       $image = get_sub_field('image');
       $content = get_sub_field('centered_text');
    ?>
    <?php if(!empty($image) && !empty($content)): ?>
      <div class="section-intro">
        <div class="slides">
            <?php while( have_rows('image_slideshow') ): the_row(); ?>
            <div class="slide intro"> 
                <?php if(!empty($image)): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php echo $content; ?>
            </div>           
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
  <?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use && instead of ||

```html
<?php if(have_rows('image_slideshow')): 
    $image = get_sub_field('image');
    $content = get_sub_field('centered_text');
?>
<?php if(!empty($image) && !empty($content)): ?>
    <div class="section-intro">
        <div class="slides">
            <?php while( have_rows('image_slideshow') ): the_row(); ?>
            <div class="slide intro"> 
                <?php if(!empty($image)): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
                <?php endif; ?>
            
                <?php echo $content; ?>
            </div>           
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

construction code show be continuos like this

```
<?php if(have_rows('image_slideshow')): 
        $image = get_sub_field('image');
        $content = get_sub_field('centered_text');

     if(!empty($image) || !empty($content)){

    echo   "<div class='section-intro'>  <div class='slides'>";
           while( have_rows('image_slideshow') )
                the_row(); 
               echo " <div class='slide intro'> ";
                    if(!empty($image))
                      echo  "<img src= $image['url'] >";

                     echo $content; 

    ?>
                </div>           

            </div>
        </div>
```